# Sorting posts by name with number through wordpress correctly

Tags: wordpress

I have 10 post with these names:

1 - "user name here"

2 - "user name here"

2.1 - "user name here"

4 - "user name here"

6 - "user name here"

11 - "user name here"

15 - "user name here"

19 - "user name here"

21 - "user name here"

26 - "user name here"

This is the way I want them to be ordered.
And I'm using this code to sort them out:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'investment',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'investor'
                )
            )
    );
```

However the result is this:

1 - "user name here"

11 - "user name here"

15 - "user name here"

19 - "user name here"

2 - "user name here"

2.1 - "user name here"

24 - "user name here"

26 - "user name here"

4 - "user name here"

6 - "user name here"

It seem like the the sorting code just looks at the first number, is there a way to fix this and have them ordered as shown first?

Answer (score 0):

When you sort by `title` is is doing an alpha sort, not numeric so you will only get the results you currently see. As a work around you could write a hook on `save_post` to parse the `post_title` and save the numeric portion to a `meta_value`. You can then use this meta value to do the sort and let WordPress know it's a number by using [`orderby=meta_value_num`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Hook for save_post:

```
function parse_number_from_title( $post_id ){
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $number = 0; // parse the number
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_number', $number );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'parse_number_from_title' );
```

Orderby meta_value

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'investment',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'title_number',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'investor'
        )
    )
);
```